# WPF listview in pyrevit -> showing properties

Tags: wpf, revit-api, pyrevit

I am a user of pyRevit and I am trying to create my own script with UI.
I am trying to create listview with view templates in revit. In this listview I want to show Name of the view templates.
Currently what I achieved can be shown on attached below image.
[image]
In this windows I need to show exact Name of template, not Autodesk.DB.ViewPlan.
Below is a snippet from my .xaml fil regarding listview.

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="138" Width="315" ItemsSource="{Binding listview}" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedIndex="1" >
   <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn/>
       </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="30" ClickMode="Press" Click="fun" />
```

I was trying to used the code DisplayMemberPath="Name" but is doesn't work.

Comment: <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnHeader" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NameOfPropertyYouWantToDisplay}"/> For more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Thanks for very quick help. It works!